# iTunesConnect Encryption of an app

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store, md5, app-store-connect

My question is about this question:

> Is your product designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography?

I don't know what to answer because my app is using the `commoncrypto` framework and `md5` encryption. What should I answer?

Codes used in App:

```
 (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input
 {
 const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
 unsigned char digest[16];
  CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), digest ); // This is the md5 call

  NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

  for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
  [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

  return  output;

 }
```

Comment: @slozano95 Hey, your code is in PHP ? so it's NOT related to iTunes Connect? Server-side implementation is not included in the scope of App Submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

md5 is a hash function and hash functions are one-way and are not encryption.

If all you are using is a hash function the answer is No you are not using encryption.

If you are using AES, DES of other encryption, that is two-way crypto functions then the answer is YES.

Merely adding the CommonCrypto framework makes no difference, it is the usage of encryption that counts.

The only concern is any encryption in the app, there is no concern with anything done on a related server.

Comment: but this does not answer the question. His question is: if commoncrypto framework is added, should he answer Yes ?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes Connect does not care server-side implementation.

If you use MD5 or any other encryption mechanism in server side (but not in App side), you should choose **No** for the answer.